# Generating function does not imply uncorrelation.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, generating-functions

A counting variable is a discrete random variable that ranges in the natural number. For each counting variable $X,$ define its generating function $f_X$ to be the polynomial $\sum_{i=0}^\infty P(X=k)t^k.$ If two random variables are independent then we know $f_{X+Y}=f_Xf_Y.$ Yet I want to find an example that $X,Y$ are not even uncorrelated but $f_{X+Y}=f_Xf_Y.$

Comment: The generating function is not a polynomials, it is a power series. A polyn9mial has a finite number of terms.

Comment: Really? Yet if X=Y I ends up with f_X(t^2) vs [f_X(t)]^2

Comment: I do not understand what your $f_X(t^2)$ is supposed to be.  I assume $[f_X(t)]^2$ is supposed to be the probability generating function $f_{X+Y}(t)$ when they are iid.

Comment: I mean, if X=Y, then f_{X+Y}=f_{2X}=f_X(t^2)

Comment: f_Xf_X=[f_X(t)]^2, which is not equal to f_X(t^2)

Comment: Whoops, yes, jumped the gun. Sorry

Comment: In general, for $|t|<1,$ $F_X(t)=E(t^{X}).$ So you need $E(t^{X+Y})=E(t^X)E(t^Y).$ When is the product of expectations equal t9 the expectation of the product? When $t^X$ and $t^Y$ are not correlated. Not sure if that helps, though.

Comment: So you'll need correlated $X,Y$ such that $t^X$ and $t^Y$ are in correlated for all $|t|<1.$

Comment: Yet how to find such X,Y, I really have no clue